# For loop stops after a while with a await/async

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await

I wrote a function to scrape a website with await/async, but the for loop inside the function stops after a while. I tried many things  but nothing works. Does someone has a idea why ? I am new in programmation, I am probably missing something out ...

```
async def extract_infos():


  titles = []
  ratings = []
  reviews = []

  for number, link in enumerate(links):
     try :
        print(f'iteration {number} sur {len(links)}')
        asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
        r = await asession.get(link)
        await r.html.arender()
        
        title = r.html.find('h1')
        title = title[0].text
        print('titre :', title[:10])
        titles.append(title)

        rating = r.html.find('.overview-rating-average')
        rating = rating[0].text
        print('rating :', rating)
        ratings.append(rating)

        review = r.html.find('.product-reviewer-reviews')
        review = review[0].text
        review = review.replace(' Reviews','')
        print('review :', review)
        reviews.append(review)
        
   
        
        f = open('info_extract.pckl', 'wb')
        pickle.dump([titles, ratings, reviews], f)
        f.close()
        
        asyncio.sleep(1)
            
    
    except:
        print(f'numero {number} n\'est pas passé')
        print('\n')
        pass
    
  return titles, ratings, reviews
```

Comment: print the exception in the except block

Comment: still doesn't work ...

Comment: First, provide a fully working example if you want people to help you... Then I recommend you abandon using global variables and don't catch exceptions with `except`; it's just some DIY... So be specific about errors; otherwise, it's impossible to debug...

Comment: Could you translate the prints to English, Am having a hard time trying to figure out what the messages say

Comment: @Maxime "print the exception" means "show us the exception"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can be running out of resources.

Move `asession = AsyncHTMLSession()` outside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It works perfectly ! You saved me from tearing my hair :)